# Convolutional keras model returns the same value on Model.predict()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

The model is trained on arrays of size (512,512,1). There are 3 classes in the data, designated {0,1,2}, which the model will need to recognize. I built it, but as a result of which I received an array with 1 unique value equal to [-2147483648].

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
df_dicom_train, df_dicom_test, df_markers_train, df_markers_test = train_test_split(df_dicom, df_markers, test_size=0.1, random_state = 42)
df_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df_dicom_train, df_markers_train))
df_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df_dicom_test, df_markers_test))

batch_size = 7
df_test = df_test.batch(batch_size=batch_size)
df_train = df_train.batch(batch_size=batch_size)
del df_dicom
del df_markers
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU

def get_model(width = 512, height = 512):

    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(width, height,1))
    x = layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(inputs)
    x = layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(x)

    #по картинке макс пуллинг должен быть размером со следующие слои
    x = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)

    x = layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(x)
    x = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)

    x = layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(x)

    x = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)

    x = layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(x)

    x = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)

    x = layers.Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(1,1), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(x)

    x = layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2,2))(x)

    x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(x)
    x = layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2,2))(x)

    x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(x)
    x = layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2,2))(x)

    x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(x)
    x = layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2,2))(x)

    x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(x)
    x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(x)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)

    return model

model = get_model()
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(df_train, batch_size = batch_size, epochs=5, validation_data=(df_test))
```

I changed the activation functions. Relu on Leaky relu, softmax and others. With relu - negative and positive values,with all others a number of different arrays with 1 unique value.Completely redesigned the model architecture, but the predict() gives the same value.
New architecture:

```
def get_model(width = 512, height = 512):

    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(width, height, 1))

    # Convolutional layers

    conv1 = layers.Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    mp1 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv1)# 256 256 96
    conv2 = layers.Conv2D(filters=144, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(mp1)
    mp2 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv2)# 128 128 144
    conv3 = layers.Conv2D(filters=192, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(mp2)
    mp3 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv3)# 64 64 192
    conv4 = layers.Conv2D(filters=576, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(mp3)
    mp4 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv4)#32 32 576
    conv5 = layers.Conv2D(filters=320, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(mp4)
    mp5 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv5)# 16 16 320

    conv6 = layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(mp5)#16 16 512
    us1 = layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2,2))(conv6)#32 32 512

    Con1 = layers.Concatenate()([us1, mp4])#32 32 1088
    conv7 = layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(Con1)# 64 64 256
    us2 = layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2,2))(conv7)

    Con2 = layers.Concatenate()([us2, mp3])# 64 64 448
    conv8 = layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(Con2)
    us3 = layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2,2))(conv8)

    Con3 = layers.Concatenate()([us3, mp2])
    conv9 = layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(Con3)
    us4 = layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2,2))(conv9)

    Con4 = layers.Concatenate()([us4, mp1])


    # Output layer
    outputs = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=(1, 1),strides = 2, activation=None)(Con4)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model

model = get_model()
model.summary()

model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Предполагается, что df_train и df_test содержат подготовленные тензоры изображений
model.fit(df_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=3, validation_data=df_test)
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True)
```

Result: array([-2147483648], dtype=int32)

Comment: This value is consistent with a signed 32-bit integer overflow.  Suggesting an element of the model, or the output is overflowing. Try a smaller array size (perhaps 1/4) and try working up from there. Or, drop the number of layers considerably, and build back up gradually. Basically, strip the model back to its core essential parts, and build up as long as the returned values are stable.

Comment: Models output floating point values, not integers, so you need to make a reproducible example for this problem, as you are probably doing some pre/post processing that produces an integer output.